# How to insert gauge meter JavaScript plugin in Jinja2 and set/update its parameters?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I found an interesting and nice gauge on the [justgage.com](http://justgage.com/) site.

[image: errors-gauge]

I really would like to insert gauge meter on my app written in the Flask and using Jinja2 templating language. But unfortunately I don't know how.

In the [above](http://justgage.com/) site they show that I just need to insert the following code:

```
<script>
  var g = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge", 
    value: 67, 
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  }); 
</script>
```

OK, but **I also would like to set and update some its parameters** (i.e. `value`, `max`, etc.) by Jinja markups `{{ }}` or in the Python and then export all (from `<script>` to `</script>`) to Jinja. For example:

```
    value: {{ my_val_from_the_database }}
```

It's possible to do that in the Jinja2 or Python/Flask? Or is there another way to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already found the answer

Yes you can assign the value from jinja

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
    var g = new JustGage({
     id: "gauge", 
     value: {{value}}, 
     min: 0,
     max: 100,
     title: {{gage_tile}}
   }); 
 </script>
.....
```

In python

```
data = {
   "value" :  custom_value,
   "gage_title" : custom_title
}

render('template.html', data)
```

Comment: Since `gage_title` is most likely going to be a string, you'll want to pass it through the [`tojson` filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#standard-filters) to handle outputting in a JavaScript-friendly format.

Comment: @onsy: Great! Thank you for your answer! PS. I do not know why but I assumed that it will not work. ;-)

Comment: You really should be using `|tojson|safe` for these items.